# setInterval function difference Date.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a function that returns every 5000 milliseconds the difference between the result of the current Date.now () method and the previous one. I am trying to make a for to store the result in each iteration and then do the subtraction but I am not able to make it work.

```js
let fecha = (Date.now())
setInterval(function () { 
  let resultado = Date.now() - fecha
  //for() {}
  console.log(resultado)
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: This seems to work, showing 5000, 10000, 15000, etc. What is your expected result?

Comment: The result is the difference between the current and previous Date.now (). Giving as an approximate result: 5008,5000, 5008. I have to store date in each iteration and subtract the previous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the current timestamp around for each iteration, otherwise you will always compare the current timestamp to the *initial* one, not the previous one:

```js
let fecha = (Date.now())
setInterval(function () { 
  let now = Date.now()
  let resultado = now - fecha
  fecha = now

  console.log(resultado)
 }, 5000);
```

---

If your issue is that it's not *exactly* 5000 milliseconds, but roughly -- that's just how the JavaScript runtime works.

`setInterval` does not guarantee execution every n milliseconds, just execution *at least n milliseconds apart*, whenever it is able to schedule the next function execution.